# TypeScript not recognising that a property is typed correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am converting a Material UI Dashboard in React to Typescript and have run into problems where TypeScript compilation fails but the property meets the criteria in the error reported.  Short version: compiling this linksStyle.jsx file

```
const linksStyle = theme => ({
  searchButton: {
    top: "-50px !important",
    marginRight: "22px",
    float: "right"
  }
});

export default linksStyle;
```

reports this error:

```
TypeScript error in C:/Dev/github/mui-dashboard/src/components/Navbars/AdminNavbarLinks.tsx(269,27):
Argument of type '(theme: any) => { searchButton: { top: string; marginRight: string; float: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Styles<Theme, {}, "searchButton">'.
  Type '(theme: any) => { searchButton: { top: string; marginRight: string; float: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleRulesCallback<Theme, {}, "searchButton">'.
    Type '{ searchButton: { top: string; marginRight: string; float: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"searchButton", CSSProperties | (() => CSSProperties)>'.
      Types of property 'searchButton' are incompatible.
        Type '{ top: string; marginRight: string; float: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | (() => CSSProperties)'.
          Type '{ top: string; marginRight: string; float: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
            Types of property 'float' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"left" | "right" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "none" | "inline-end" | "inline-start" | undefined'.  TS2345

    267 | }
    268 | 
  > 269 | export default withStyles(linksStyle)(AdminNavbarLinks);
        |                           ^
    270 |
```

From the last line of the error it appears that TypeScript is expecting `float` to have one of the values: `'"left" | "right" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "none" | "inline-end" | "inline-start" | undefined'`, which it does have.  If I remove the `float: "right"` property from linksStyle.jsx, the code compiles, so that is definitely the line causing the error.

`withStyles` is a Material UI wrapper function, in my case v4.2: the type definitions can be seen [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.0/packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.d.ts).

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.  The original `linksStyle` was much more complex and had multiple similar problems reported, I have cut it down to the minimum which reports the problem.

Comment: Maybe try `float: "right" as "right"`

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem with two actions.  Thank you to @ferhen for the pointer.

1. The first problem was that I had not yet changed the type if the linkStyles file from .jsx to .tsx.  I did that and resolved the various typing warnings and errors reported.
2. Then I needed to change all properties with types defined as a list of possible strings, like the `float` example above, to use the `"value" as "value"` syntax suggested by @ferhan.  Note that this does not work in a .jsx file - not valid syntax.

Comment: Don't do `"value" as "value"`. Use `as const` instead: `const linksStyle = theme => ({
    searchButton: {
        top: "-50px !important",
        marginRight: "22px",
        float: "right"
    } as const
});`

Comment: Thanks, don't understand this syntax but will read up and try it out.